# How to Configure Registrationless COM Components

Tags: com, configuration, registry

I'm in need of distributing several old COM applications that are to be installed on locked down computers. I'm trying to get these applications to launch without having to be registered in the registry via regsvr32 or in the case of an EXE component via the /regserver switch. I can control and locally copy all the required dependencies in this scenario.

I know this is possible, however, I'm having a real tough time piecing together the different pieces or finding coherent information on how to set this up.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Reg-free activation of out-of-process servers (EXEs) is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has a good tutorial on [Registration Free COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx).

There are two basic parts to getting registration free COM working.

First, you need to convert the COM dlls to an assebmly: Just the COM dll's, and create a manifest describing them, and give it a name. Bundle this assembly in the same folder as your application.

Next, you need to tell your application to use the assembly you just created. When COM tries to create a new object, it will first look in any assemblies registered in the default activation context, before looking in the registry.

Answer (score 1):

Registrationless COM can be tricky to set up but the overall process is not very complex. I wrote up my process along with some tools that help with debugging problems in a blog post here:

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/Oct/09/An-easy-way-to-create-Side-by-Side-registrationless-COM-Manifests-with-Visual-Studio

FWIW, registrationless COM doesn't work with DCOM EXE servers unfortunately - only DLL servers are supported.